# How do I bind to an existing item in an NSCollectionViewItem?

Tags: mvvmcross, monomac

An NSCollectionViewItem is derived from NSViewController. I use it as a prototype in an NSCollectionView. It has a property called RepresentedObject. Normally, I would use something like

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<DevViewController, DevViewModel> ();
set.Bind (devTextField).To (vm => vm.Text);
set.Bind (devTextView).To (vm => vm.BigText);
```

to bind UI elements with the vm. In the case of the NSCollectionViewItem, I want to bind to properties in the RepresentedObject. How do I do this?

NSCollectionView.Content takes NSObject[]. I'm currently taking my List and making an NSObject[] where each item in there is NSObject.FromObject(myClass) - which itself may not be the right approach.

Thanks in advance!

**Update.** It seems that if I can make my NSObject a KVO'd object ala http://cocoa-mono.org/archives/153/kvc-kvo-and-cocoa-bindings-oh-my-part-1/ that the bindings would automatically work.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach of MvvmCross and its binding layer is that:

- it tries to work with native controls,
- but it also tries to encourage you to keep your ViewModel objects independent and unaware of any native choices.

So if you're trying to use a native control which requires you to supply a `NSObject[]` array, and you want to display (say) a list of customers, then a reasonable design choice within MvvmCross would be:

- within the ViewModel:

  - to use a `Customer` object which provides `INotifyPropertyChanged`
  - to supply a `List<Customer>` as a parameter on your ViewModel
- within the View:

  - to supply a `NSObject[]`
- somewhere between the two

  - find:

    - a way of mapping your `List<>` to an `[]`
    - and find a way of mapping your `Customer` to an `NSObject`
  - this can be found either:

    - using inheritance of the View and providing a custom C# property for binding
    - or using a custom binding
    - or using a value converter

The challenge of mapping the `Customer` to an `NSObject` is a particularly interesting one. If your end view is looking for KVO type functionality then I believe the conversion can be done by using a small Converter class which maps `ValueForKey`/`SetValueForKey` to their .Net reflection equivalent, and which maps `INotifyPropertyChanged` events to their `DidChangeValue` NSObject equivalent. I've not personally done this... but it feels like it should be doable, and (with a little caching of `PropertyInfo` objects) it should probably be reasonably efficient too.

---

Some final notes:

- if you are marshalling a **lot** of calls between KVO and .Net reflection and this does impact your application's performance, then you may find using `Rio` style Field binding might be a faster experience, or you may find that it's faster to write hard-coded non-reflection based wrappers for your specific types.
- if your ViewModel collection is mutable - e.g. it supports `INotifyCollectionChanged` then there may also be other interesting and reasonably efficient ways you can respond to the collection change events - although your view may not support these particularly 'beautifully' without some additional animation work.